# Visual Basic application returning a 550 error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have a Visual Basic .net desktop application that was originally designed to find Windows CE 5.0 devices on an ethernet network via IP address.

When it finds a device, it will copy the SQL Compact database ( 3.5 SP1) .sdf file out of the device and onto the users local PC for manipulation using the WebClient class.

Recently, we had to change the Windows device and it is now running Compact Embedded 7 with SQL Compact database version 3.5 SP2.

Now, when the Visual Basic application is run, it finds the device via IP address, but throws an exception of 550, file not found or no access.

The file is in the correct location, and as far as I can tell, all the correct file access rights are in place on the device.

Does anyone know of any potential issues migrating from CE 5.0 to EC 7 or with SQL Compact Embedded 3.5 SP1 to 3.5 SP2 that could be causing an exception of 550 being thrown?

Here is the code that is throwing the exception: *fileTransfer.DownloadFile(IPAddr, localTempFile)*

IPAddr is a string that is passed that contains the database file path on the CE device.  localTempFile is the location to store a copy of the database on the users local PC.

'Retrieve physical location info to create folder name for backups
    Public Shared Function retrieveFolderInfo(ByVal IPAddr As String, ByVal localTempFile As String)

```
    Dim fileTransfer As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim dataReader As SqlCeDataReader
    Dim folderName As String = ""

   fileTransfer.DownloadFile(IPAddr, localTempFile)
```

Comment: Sounds like a web issue, not related to sqlce

Comment: Have you wrapped it in a try catch to see the actual error? This error message is very generic and does not help the user to figure out what exactly causes this issue. Can you post relevant code?

Comment: Sounds more like an FTP issue to me.  When you say "the file is in the correct location", is that the file on the PC or the device?  550 could also mean Access Denied (Permission denied).  For grins, you could try to manually FTP to the new and old devices and see how they behave.  My guess would be that EC7 has more restrictions than CE5.

Comment: The VB application ran fine before.  The only variables that have changed are on the Windows device.  It was migrated from Windows CE  5.0 to Compact Embedded 7, and that forced the SQL Compact database to change from 3.5 SP1 to 3.5 SP2.

Comment: ErikEJ, could you please elaborate on what you mean by a web issue?  Duston, what I mean about the file is in the correct location, I am referring to the .sdf file on the Windows Compact device that the VB app is attempting to copy.  You are also correct about EC7 being more restrictive than CE 5, but I thought I had eliminated those issues from what I had read on the MS forums.